# php popup window issue

Tags: php, jquery, get, popup, show

i have three popup windows, that are supposed show if the `$_GET` variable `$message` is: `changeSuccess` or `changeSuccessMenu` or `changeSuccessEvent`. The problem here is that even if this value is `changeSuccessEvent` it still shows the second one which is: `changeSuccessMenu`. Please help.

Code(PHP):

```
                    $message = $_GET['message'];
                    if($message == "changeSuccess")
                    {
                        echo '
                        <script type="text/javascript">
                        $(document).ready(function()
                        {
                            $("#screenCover").slideToggle("slow");
                            $("#closePopup").click(function()
                            {
                                $("#screenCover").slideToggle("slow");
                                setTimeout(resetPage, 600);
                            });
                        });
                        function resetPage()
                        {
                            window.location.replace("../admin/admintable.php?page=main");
                        }
                        </script>
                        <div id="screenCover" style="display:none;">
                        <div id="popup">
                        <div id="closePopupMain">
                        <p id="closePopup"><a href="#">X</a></p>
                        </div>
                        <p id="success">La page à éte modifiée!</p>
                        </div>
                        </div>';
                    }
                    else if($message = "changeSuccessMenu")
                    {
                        echo '
                        <script type="text/javascript">
                        $(document).ready(function()
                        {
                            $("#screenCover").slideToggle("slow");
                            $("#closePopup").click(function()
                            {
                                $("#screenCover").slideToggle("slow");
                                setTimeout(resetPage, 600);
                            });
                        });
                        function resetPage()
                        {
                            window.location.replace("../admin/admintable.php?page=main");
                        }
                        </script>
                        <div id="screenCover" style="display:none;">
                        <div id="popup">
                        <div id="closePopupMain">
                        <p id="closePopup"><a href="#">X</a></p>
                        </div>
                        <p id="success">Le menu à éte créer/modifiée!</p>
                        </div>
                        </div>';
                    }
                    else if($message = "changeSuccessEvent")
                    {
                        echo '
                        <script type="text/javascript">
                        $(document).ready(function()
                        {
                            $("#screenCover").slideToggle("slow");
                            $("#closePopup").click(function()
                            {
                                $("#screenCover").slideToggle("slow");
                                setTimeout(resetPage, 600);
                            });
                        });
                        function resetPage()
                        {
                            window.location.replace("../admin/admintable.php?page=main");
                        }
                        </script>
                        <div id="screenCover" style="display:none;">
                        <div id="popup">
                        <div id="closePopupMain">
                        <p id="closePopup"><a href="#">X</a></p>
                        </div>
                        <p id="success">L\'événement à éte créer/modifiée!</p>
                        </div>
                        </div>';
                    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**It should be `==` while comparing**. Your `if` is ok but in `else-if`s you are having only `=` wherein it should have been `==` and if your `changeSuccessEvent` is the only condition remaining then just use `else` instead of `else if` as below:

```
if($message == "changeSuccess")
{
     //code
}
else if($message == "changeSuccessMenu")
{
     //code
}
else 
{
     //code           
}
```

Comment: Well this sort of minor things happen while coding.. :)

Comment: Yeah i know, i'm just tired and missed that little detail

Answer (score 0):

make sure the next time you try to compare use **==** and not ***assign (=)***

try the following

```
                $message = $_GET['message'];
                if($message == "changeSuccess")
                {
                    echo '
                    <script type="text/javascript">
                    $(document).ready(function()
                    {
                        $("#screenCover").slideToggle("slow");
                        $("#closePopup").click(function()
                        {
                            $("#screenCover").slideToggle("slow");
                            setTimeout(resetPage, 600);
                        });
                    });
                    function resetPage()
                    {
                        window.location.replace("../admin/admintable.php?page=main");
                    }
                    </script>
                    <div id="screenCover" style="display:none;">
                    <div id="popup">
                    <div id="closePopupMain">
                    <p id="closePopup"><a href="#">X</a></p>
                    </div>
                    <p id="success">La page à éte modifiée!</p>
                    </div>
                    </div>';
                }
                else if($message == "changeSuccessMenu")
                {
                    echo '
                    <script type="text/javascript">
                    $(document).ready(function()
                    {
                        $("#screenCover").slideToggle("slow");
                        $("#closePopup").click(function()
                        {
                            $("#screenCover").slideToggle("slow");
                            setTimeout(resetPage, 600);
                        });
                    });
                    function resetPage()
                    {
                        window.location.replace("../admin/admintable.php?page=main");
                    }
                    </script>
                    <div id="screenCover" style="display:none;">
                    <div id="popup">
                    <div id="closePopupMain">
                    <p id="closePopup"><a href="#">X</a></p>
                    </div>
                    <p id="success">Le menu à éte créer/modifiée!</p>
                    </div>
                    </div>';
                }
                else if($message == "changeSuccessEvent")
                {
                    echo '
                    <script type="text/javascript">
                    $(document).ready(function()
                    {
                        $("#screenCover").slideToggle("slow");
                        $("#closePopup").click(function()
                        {
                            $("#screenCover").slideToggle("slow");
                            setTimeout(resetPage, 600);
                        });
                    });
                    function resetPage()
                    {
                        window.location.replace("../admin/admintable.php?page=main");
                    }
                    </script>
                    <div id="screenCover" style="display:none;">
                    <div id="popup">
                    <div id="closePopupMain">
                    <p id="closePopup"><a href="#">X</a></p>
                    </div>
                    <p id="success">L\'événement à éte créer/modifiée!</p>
                    </div>
                    </div>';
                }
```